# unable to install Boto3 on windows

Tags: python, boto3

I am getting below exception after running pip install boto3 command

> ```
> C:\boto3-develop>pip install boto3
> ```
>
> Collecting boto3
>       Downloading boto3-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
>           100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 281kB/s
>
> Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3)
>         Downloading jmespath-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3)   Downloading
>   s3transfer-0.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 787kB/s
>
> Collecting botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from boto3)   Downloading
>   botocore-1.5.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.4MB 81kB/s
>
> Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)
>   Downloading docutils-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (536kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 542kB 205kB/s
>
> Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from
>   botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)   Downloading
>   python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 273kB/s
>
> Collecting six>=1.5 (from
>   python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->b oto3)
>   Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Installing collected packages: jmespath, docutils, six,
>   python-dateutil, botocor e, s3transfer, boto3
>
> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py" , line 215, in
>   main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\instal l.py", line
>   342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py" , line 784, in
>   install
>       **kwargs
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install .py", line
>   851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install .py", line
>   1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line  345, in
>   move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line  316, in
>   clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)
>
> File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__. py", line 83,
>   in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)
>
> File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in
>   makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files
>   (x86)\python 36-32\Lib\site-packages\jmespath'

```
C:\boto3-develop>
```

Comment: Access is denied indicates that you do not have the permission, try running it as admin

Comment: You can get rid such error using virtualenv or  install your development deployment using vagrant

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are running the command line as administrator. Lack of privileges often prevents installation of python packages.